# How to get the line number that triggers error in TRY-CATCH?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know what actions is triggering the error in my TRY-CATCH block.

```
async function () {
      try {

      }
      catch (err) {
         console.log(`${err} in line ${ /* ??? */ }.`);
      }
}
```

Anyone knows the answer or could give me some directions as to where I can find it myself ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is no guaranteed information for this. You could [try to get the stack trace](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-stack-trace) but the data you get is not necessarily uniform. There is `console.trace()` but it just directly prints the information, doesn't allow you to examine it programmatically.

Comment: try to see `err.stack`, maybe it will show useful info

Comment: Stepping trough the try catch block with the debugger might be a helpfull tool as well.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I used the err.stack along with some string methods (slice() and indexOf()) to locate the line number and print it.  Not the best method but I'll use it unless someone suggests otherwise.